Why i can start my visit my website on localhost JSON file website
I have a problem, as you can see in the picture, I'm trying to run a website on live server (localhost) but it's not working and I don't understand why and what I'm doing wrong?

I have tried to see how to integrate the html with JavaScript but it didn't work at all, so I need help to understand where I'm going wrong.

what do you see when you ask for http://127.0.0.1:5500/gallery.json? Or when you click on that link?

Just make sure your main html file is placed in the root of the project folder. Rename it to index.html, then reload your live server. This should resolve your issue.

I Could some one or KIKO SOFTWARE Can you give your Whatsapp or something and there you can maybe help ? Because after this link i see same json file like on Visual studio

JSON files aren't webpages, they only carry data, so even if you open them in a browser you will only see the data they contain. As Pratyush Goutam suggested, your browser needs HTML web pages. Sorry, no I do not do WhatsApp consultations.

I'm curious to know what you were expecting.  I don't see any HTML or Javascript here, only JSON files.  Do you have HTML?  Javascript files use a .js extension, not .json, but there has to be an HTML file to load the first one.
